# Auto Pointer in Bada

Tags: pointers, memory, bada

Do anyone know any way to use `smart_ptr` (Smart Pointer) or `auto_ptr` (Auto Pointer) in Bada OS? 
Bada OS has no `std` namespace, so, Boost library porting is really difficult. 
Perhaps there is another way for memory managing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Bada 1.0, [STL are availables](http://developer.bada.com/help_2.0/index.jsp?topic=/com.osp.cppapireference.help/group__Cplusplus.html) :

> The bada application supports C++ based on the Standard C++ ANSI ISO 14882 2003, which includes the Standard Template Library (STL). This helps developers migrate the pre-existing standard library based applications to the bada platform with minimum effort. More specifically, bada supports an essential subset of libstdc++v3 (http://gcc.gnu.org/libstdc++/) comprising a full set of standard C++ functions specified in standard C++ ANSI ISO 14882 2003 and the entire Standard Template Library (http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/). These standard C++ functions are frequently used.

Regarding Boost, boost 1.37 shared_ptr works perfect.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <auto_ptr>
using namespace std;

///...


auto_ptr<ByteBuffer> bb(new ByteBuffer());
bb->Construct(71);
```